# hide get variables in url .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to Hide Get variables

```
http://fun.megsta.com/apps/BreakingNews_/?width=1000
```

I was try this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index/([^/-]+)-([^/-]+)/?$ index.php?r=$1&width=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Here i got this Get variable URL To Get screen width

```
<?  if(!isset($_GET['width']))     
{     
echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\">     
<!--      
document.location=\"$PHP_SELF?width=\"+screen.width;     
//-->     
</script>";     
}     
else {         

// Code to be displayed if resolutoin is detected     
 if(isset($_GET['width'])) {     
           // Resolution  detected     
 }     
 else {     
           // Resolution not detected     
 }     
 } 
 ?>
```

Comment: you want to make actual url like this: `http://fun.megsta.com/apps/1/1000` ?

Comment: yes Like this apps/1000

Comment: What is the URL that you want to show in browser?

Comment: fun.megsta.com/apps/1000